# How to make a folder in i18n-node and have multiple json files of a same language?

Tags: json, internationalization, i18n-node

I have watched a [video of a coursera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO0BFNCyugQ&t=10s), where the speaker stated that in locales folder they have folders for each language and in the folder language there are json files of each single page.

So my question is how to implement it in i18n?

Example of a pattern:

```
app.js
--locales
----en
------home.json
------about.json
----de
------home.json
------about.json
```

Thank you!